# Angular2 index.html include CSS Styling

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I have a little problem with Angular2 and a CSS-Stylesheet.
I included boostrap in the index.html file of the Angular2-App.
It is no problem in the whole application...
Then I included another library (Bootstrap-switch) in the same way:

```
<!-- Load external Libraries / Modules -->
<!-- Bootstrap & JQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Bootstrap Toggle Switch -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>

<!-- eigener Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

But now I have a little problem:
While the "normal" Bootstrap is functional over the entire application, the Bootstrap Toggle I can only use at the `index.html`.
If I use it there, no problem, but if I use it at any other page, the styles won´t apply...

Here is how I use the toggle-switch:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label><input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" value="">Passwort
        speichern (Auto-Login)</label>
</div>
```

Can someone can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you check your console?

Comment: I already checked my console, but there´s nothing related to this... :/

Comment: Maybe some of the styles are overridden. Or maybe the stylesheet is not loaded. You must ensure that there's no error in your console.

Comment: Mh, i don´t think styles are overridden...
But: I have one error:
Die Verbindung zu ws://localhost:3000/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=IgRVIwp5KyBa3JnKAADe wurde unterbrochen, während die Seite geladen wurde.
I´m using the lite-server, maybe it is because of this...